# AngularJS - Multiple binding - calculating input values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm building a large form with AngularJS which will replace a huge excel spreadsheet with a lot of formulas and functions. In short, this form is a calculator - where a lot of values are depending on previous values. My current approach is to add ng-change on all inputs that affect next ones - also adding watchers to those fields that change programmatically. I find this way of doing very confusing and hard to maintain. Any better patterns of doing that kind of work?

The complete form I'm building consists of 60+ fields that interact with each other. All calculated values, like "price" in example are subject to manual change or override. So the calculation of "total price" in example below should be automatic whether price is calculated via previous values or manually changed.

Small example:

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Calculator</h2>

  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <form>
        <li>Width (cm): <input type="text" ng-change="changePrice()" ng-model="width"/> </li>
        <li>Height (cm): <input type="text" ng-change="changePrice()" ng-model="height"/> </li>
        <li>Depth (cm)<input type="text" ng-change="changePrice()" ng-model="depth"/>  </li>   
        <li>Price per cm3<input type="text" ng-change="changePrice()" ng-model="priceCm"/>  </li>
        <li><b>Price</b><input type="text" ng-model="price"/>  <br/><br/></li>
        <li>Packaging price<input type="text" ng-change="changeTotalPrice()" ng-model="packagePrice"/>  </li>
        <li><b>Total price</b><input type="text" ng-model="total"/>  </li>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.$watch('price', function(newValue,oldValue){
    if(newValue != oldValue)
    {
        $scope.changeTotalPrice();
    }
});

$scope.changePrice = function(){
    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;
    var depth = 0;
    var priceCm = 0;

    width = $scope.width;
    height = $scope.height;
    depth = $scope.depth;
    priceCm = $scope.priceCm;

    if(width > 0 && height > 0 && depth > 0 && priceCm > 0)
    {
        $scope.price = width * height * depth * priceCm;
    }          
}

$scope.changeTotalPrice = function(){
    var price = 0;
    var packaging = 0;

    price = $scope.price;
    packaging = $scope.packagePrice;

    if(price > 0 && packaging > 0)
    {
        $scope.total = price*1 + packaging*1;
    }          
  }
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rewnao6p/3/

Comment: Don't just link to a fiddle. The warning you got when you tried to submit the answer with only a fiddle link should have been clear enough in that regard. Please post a small sample of your code that reproduces the problem, instead.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is a better way to do this: since your total depends on the rest of the value, compute the total dynamically

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {

 $scope.price = function(){
    var width = $scope.width;
    var height = $scope.height;
    var depth = $scope.depth;
    var priceCm = $scope.priceCm;

    if(width > 0 && height > 0 && depth > 0 && priceCm > 0)
    {
        return width * height * depth * priceCm;
    }          
}

 $scope.totalPrice = function(){        
    var price = $scope.price();
    var packaging = $scope.packagePrice;

    if(price > 0 && packaging > 0)
    {
        return price*1 + packaging*1;
    }          
 }

}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g7p7ho6z/

Comment: I tried this way, but then I can't manually change/override price and calculation does not continue.

Comment: Well that's another issue, if you detail it in your question, we might be able to help you. This is an answer for the current question